# How to give a __init__ parameter when initializing a class through a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
maps = {'object': object()
    }

start_scene = 'object'

def next_scene(scene_name):
    return maps.get(scene_name)

def opening_scene()
    return next_scene(start_scene)

current_scene = opening_scene()
```

I want to pass a value when initializing the object to its `__init__` method. There is probably an obvious answer to this but I don't know of it. Please correct me if I'm using the wrong terms; I'm a beginner.

edit: This is how I would be doing it if it weren't in a dictionary

```
first = object1()
second = object2(first) # its this i want do to
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us how you want to initialize the object if it wasn’t in a dictionary, and then we can tell you how it works with your existing code?

Comment: i made an edit, hope it was what you were looking for

Comment: So you kind of want to pass the previous scene to the new scene object?

Comment: Is `maps = {'object': object(yourArgumentsHere)}` what you're looking for? If not, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, it seems like what im looking for. If you mind would you give me an example on how to do it in my sample?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Why are you using a dictionary instead of a class, since all scene share a common pattern, they all have a previous scene, a next scene and so on.

```
class Scene(object):
    all = {}

    def __init__(self, name, next_scene, previous_scene=None):
        self.name = name
        self.next_scene = next_scene
        self.previous_scene = previous_scene

        self.__class__.all[name] = self

    @classmethod
    def opening_scene(cls):
        return cls.all['Opening']

opening = Scene(name='Opening', next_scene='First')
first = Scene(name='First', next_scene='Second', previous_scene=opening)
second = Scene(name='Second', next_scene='Third', previous_scene=first)
```

First we create a class named `Scene`, it has one `class attribute`: `all` which is where we store all the scenes created, you could store it outside the class, but I find this way more elegant. And a `classmethod` `opening_scene` in case you need to quickly get the opening scene.

In the `__init__` we have 3 attributes, `scene name`, `next_scene` and `previous_scene`, the latter is set by default to None, which means if we don't provide one, it will be set to None.

The line `self.__class__.all[scene_name] = self` is where we store the scene in the `all` dictionary. It's the same as writing `Scene.all[scene_name] = self`, but we don't have to hardcode the name of the class `Scene`.

Then we initialize three scenes, the first is the opening, which doesn't have a previous scene, and so it will be None by default, the other two have, and are set using the variable name, instead of a string.

There's many other ways you could do it, you could use strings to get the previous scene, but this would require to set a `@property`, or something else.

Maybe I didn't grasp what is your problem, if you think this is the wrong approach, please explain what is your intend, and I'll try to address it.

---

## EDIT:

Here's an example using `@property` and only strings.

```
class Scene(object):
    all = {}

    def __init__(self, name, next_scene, previous_scene=None):
        self.name = name
        self.previous_scene = previous_scene
        self._next_scene = next_scene

        self.__class__.all[name] = self

    @classmethod
    def opening_scene(cls):
        return cls.all['Opening']

    @property
    def next_scene(self):
        try:
            return self.__class__.all[self._next_scene]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError("There's no %s Scene." % self._next_scene)

Scene(name='Opening', next_scene='First')
Scene(name='First', next_scene='Second', previous_scene='Opening')
Scene(name='Second', next_scene='Third', previous_scene='First')

scene = Scene.opening_scene()
while True:
    print "Scene:", scene.name
    print "\tPrevious:", scene.previous_scene
    try:
        print "\tNext:", scene.next_scene.name
        scene = scene.next_scene
    except KeyError as err:
        print err.message
        break
    print ""
```

Outputs:

```
Scene: Opening
    Previous: None
    Next: First

Scene: First
    Previous: Opening
    Next: Second

Scene: Second
    Previous: First
    Next: There's no Third Scene.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a dictionary with scene types (note that these are types, or classes, and not actually already initialized instances):

```
maps = {
    'first': StartScene,
    'second': OtherScene
}
```

Each scene class’es `__init__` has a parameter that takes the previous scene, which may be `None` for the first scene. Then you can build a construct like this:

```
previous_scene = None
def next_scene (name):
    global previous_scene

    # get the type from the dictionary
    scene_type = maps[name]

    # call that type to instantiate a new scene, and pass the previous scene
    new_scene = scene_type(previous_scene)

    # update the previous scene variable
    previous_scene = new_scene

    # return the new scene
    return new_scene
```